# How to convert DateTimeOffset to DateTime in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this query which returns incorrect results:

```
 return contextProvider
                      .Context
                      .OrderAccounts
                      .Where(orderAccount => listCSRId.Contains(orderAccount.OrderCust.UserId) &&
                                    orderAccount.OrderCust.SubmittedDate >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate)
                                    && orderAccount.OrderCust.SubmittedDate <= startDate
                                    && orderAccount.OrderCust.OrderStatusId == (int)OrderStatus.Submitted)
                       .Select(x => new Order
                       {
                         UserId = x.OrderCust.UserId,
                         FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode,
                         GreenFlag = x.GreenFlag ?? false,
                         Payable = x.Payable,
                         OrderCustId = x.OrderCustId
                       })
                      .ToList();
```

The reason that the results are incorrect is that the SubmittedDate is a DateTimeOffSet in Sql Server.  So when the local DateTime of 11 PM on 2017-11-15 is stored, it is stored as 04:00 2017-11-16 due to the Offset between local time, and GMT.

When the query runs, the startDate is just a date without a time.  So what is needed is to convert the SubmittedDate in the table to a Local Date.  Then the query would be correct.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why not just convert `startDate` to `DateTimeOffset` instead?

Comment: And this is why you should always store DateTimes in UTC in your database. Everything thing else is presentation, and doesn't belong in your database. I realise this doesn't answer your question, but it would have avoided it.

Comment: Because the time portion is not used.  I need all order submitted on a certain date regardless of time.  If I converted to DateTimeOffset, and then dropped the time portion, it would now return orders from the wrong date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the 'startDate' parameter was a DateTime, instead of a DateTimeOffset.

When this parameter was changed to a DateTimeOffset, then the queries started working properly.

In other words, a DateTimeOffset with a value of `2017-11-15 00:00` with an offset of -5:00 is converted to a UTC of `2017-11-15 05:00` (with no Offset). I think EntityFramework/Sql Server is smart enough to compare DateTimeOffsets correctly, it doing the conversion to UTC (with no offset) somewhere along the line)

So now any submitted date greater than `2017-11-15 05:00` is returned which is what I wanted (the current day records - local time being 2017-11-15 00:00).

Time is such a slippery subject, hopefully I have explained this correctly.

The takeway is: Compare Sql Server DateTimeOffsets  with a .net DateTimeOffset, not a DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the `startDate` to UTC, and add 1 day and convert and make sure the `SubmittedDate` is between the two:

```
return contextProvider
                      .Context
                      .OrderAccounts
                      .Where(orderAccount => listCSRId.Contains(orderAccount.OrderCust.UserId) &&
                                    orderAccount.OrderCust.SubmittedDate >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate.ToUniversalTime())
                                    && orderAccount.OrderCust.SubmittedDate < startDate.AddDays(1).ToUniversalTime()
                                    && orderAccount.OrderCust.OrderStatusId == (int)OrderStatus.Submitted)
                       .Select(x => new Order {
                           UserId = x.OrderCust.UserId,
                           FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode,
                           GreenFlag = x.GreenFlag ?? false,
                           Payable = x.Payable,
                           OrderCustId = x.OrderCustId
                       })
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work for me.  See below for what did.

Comment: -1 as the poster didn't verify his or her assumption that "ToUniversalTime()" is a supported EF operation (which it is not)

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTimeOffset ToUniversalTime()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @PaulMSorauer What makes you think EF is involved? Also, `startDate` is a local value, not an EF field from a SQL column, so the expression should be evaluated on the client. A quick test with LINQ to SQL / EF Core 2.2.6 / EF Core 3.1 shows that works fine.

Comment: Apologies. As you pointed out, I did in fact not recognise that startDate was a local variable and when I tested in EF 6 I used a datetimeoffset in the DB, which is why it failed. Apologies for my misunderstanding. I'm trying to upvote this back.